# Finding the lowest value in a list between 2 indices recursively

Tags: python, list, recursion

I currently have recursive function

```
def RecursiveMin(L):
    if len(L)==2:
        if L[0]<L[1]:
            return L[0]
        else:
            return L[1]
    else:
        X= RecursiveMin(L[1:])
        if L[0]<X:
            return L[0]
        else:
            return X
```

How can I modify this/create a function to where I can limit the search of the minimum value to be be only between 2 indices in a form like RecursiveMin(L, start, end)?

Comment: By calling it with `RecursiveMin(your_list[start+1:end])` (exclusive) or `RecursiveMin(your_list[start:end+1])` (inclusive)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great use of recursion.  Is there a special reason you're doing it this way?

Comment: Newbie practicing python recursion, not great with implementation yet

Comment: Try implementing the binary search algorithm. That would be better practice.